# What sort of tests would you use to test this

Tags: testing

I have a random number generator that takes in two arguments and generates a random number between them. This is exposed as an Restful API. What sort of tests would you use to test this?
This is not as obvious as it may seem.

Comment: I'm not a statistician, but the phrase _chi-squared_ comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's better to devide your tests to two parts:

- API tests for Restful API;
- Functional tests for randomizer function.